# Regex - Extract Text Between Email Addresses

Tags: regex

From the text below I need to extract emails and the names as well.

```
Vicente Clark
vicente.clark@gmail.com
Mark van der Zant
mark.zant@protonmail.com
Georgy Collins
georgy.collins@yahoo.com
Paul Danilsson
paul.danilsson@live.com
```

I've already figured out the email part, but I need to store the names in a separate variable.

The text might not be always formatted so well with the new lines.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Mark van der Zant mark.zant@protonmail.com how it should be possible?

Comment: I would like to extract the whole name, not just the first name. So the array would contain ['Vicente Clar','Mark van der Zant', etc.

Comment: What language do you use ? Php ? Python ? JS ?...

Comment: i'm using JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
(?:^|\r?\n)(.*?)\r?\n(.*?@.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)
```

- `(?:)` a non-matching group (otherwise this would be the first `$1`)
- `^|\r?\n` a linebreak (Windows `\r\n` or UNIX `\n`) or the beginning of the string (the first entry does not have a linebreak in the beginning)
- `(.*?)` anything, but as few characters as possible (until the next line break)
- `(.*?@.*?)` matches an e-mail address, but without any validation other than it has to have an `@` character in it
- `(?=\r?\n|$)` the pattern has to be followed by `\r?\n|$`, but it does not match (this is necesary, otherwise, the linebreak afterwards would already be part of the this match and therefore cannot be part of the next match). `\r?\n|$` matches a linebreak or the end of a string.
- Make sure to use the global flag to match more than one occurence (`/g` in the end)

*If the text is "not always so well formatted with the linebreaks", you need to provide more information on how it might be structured otherwise. Regex relies on fixed patterns and needs to handle every possibility separately.*

**Here is an example in JavaScript:**

```js
var text = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
var regex = /(?:^|\r?\n)(.*?)\r?\n(.*?@.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)/g;

var match = regex.exec(text);
while(match !== null) {
  console.log(match[1] + ":", match[2]);
  match = regex.exec(text);
}
```

```css
#main {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">Vicente Clark
vicente.clark@gmail.com
Mark van der Zant
mark.zant@protonmail.com
Georgy Collins
georgy.collins@yahoo.com
Paul Danilsson
paul.danilsson@live.com</div>
```

Comment: it will be a user input.. the users are supposed to enter the text in the format above - name + new line + email... i expect that the name will be always before the email, but it might happen that the new line is left out

Comment: You could try something like [`(?:^|\r?\n)(.*?)(?: |\r?\n)([^\s]+?@.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bpCVbJ/1). This takes everything in front of the `@` which is not a whitespace and uses it as part of the e-mail address. It enforces a space or a linebreak between the e-mail address and the name.

Comment: it works well... with the example from the comment it works even if the linebreak is missing... the only case when I had the issue was when the linebreak wa missing between the previous email and the next name

Comment: Okay, then use [`(?: |^|\r?\n)(.*?)(?: |\r?\n)([^\s]+?@[^\s]+?)(?= |\r?\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bpCVbJ/3). This should work in every case.